# Add/change session variable only on click on an element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

On my web i have a button. On click on it i want to add a var called key in clients $_SESSION array.. I`m doing it with AJAX like so:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $.get('engine.php', {key: 1}, function(data) {
    console.log('You grabbed the key..');
    });
});
```

In engine.php i`m doing this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['key'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['key'] = true;
}
```

But it is not good for security reasons.. Every user can type in console a get request and get this var.. How should i do it so the user can get this var only by clicking on a button ?

Comment: There is nothing you can do if the business logic is in the client.

Comment: Using `POST` request, maybe?

Comment: I think i`ve found a way..
<button onclick="<?php $_SESSION['key'] = 1; ?>">Add var</button>

Comment: (rofl) Well.. yes, it's very simple, but this way user cant cheat and add this var some other way.. Correct me if i'm wrong! :)

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong.  That above code will insert the button into the page *and* set the key value to 1, before it is sent to your browser.  You need to remember that *all* PHP is run on the server *before* anything is shown in the browser.  You cannot run PHP in the browser.  What you'll need to do is make the button make an AJAX call to a PHP page that sets the session variable for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. Well, thats exactly what i'm doing, but this is not secure.. This way user can on his own write a code in js console and add this var without even clicking on the button.. But i want to add this var to $_SESSION only by clicking on the button.. Is there some possible way?

Comment: Well.. i think i've found a way.. (2 try!). I've placed a some.php file outside the root folder and created not button, but the <a> tag with a  href="../some.php" .. I think that now user can only add this var to $_SESSION only by clicking on that <a> tag.. Correct me if i'm wrong 2.

Comment: Aaaand this works only for including files on webpage.. :\